# Can't get last 2 characters in token, and for loop returns first token in a vaiable

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, token, rename

Ok, here's the set up:

I have a ton of text files with the following format:

```
filename## time Description of file with spaces
```

I'm trying to rename the actual file on disk with the description of the file, using a for loop:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%a IN (%1) DO call :rename %%a %%b "%%c"
goto :eof
:rename
set origfilename=%1
set last2=%1:~-2%
set time=%2
set "multiword=%~3"

ren %origfilename%.ext "%last2%_%time%_%multiword%.ext"

set origfilename=
set last2=
set time=
set multiword=
```

Here's what's happening:

last2 is never picking up the last 2 characters of the original file name, and if I echo %3 after the DO instead of the call to :rename, it has the full token with spaces. When I try to use %3 in the loop, it only contains the first token of %3.
I tried using setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion before the for, but it didn't work as I expected.

Am I trying to do too many things at once? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Edit your post and show 3 of your actual filenames.

Comment: Actually, a sample of the input (entire line) and result would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this will do what you want.

```
@echo off 
for /f "Tokens=1,2,3*" %%a in ('dir /b filename*') do (
   call :rename "%%a %%b %%c %%d" %%a %%b "%%c %%d")
goto :eof
:rename full orig time new
echo %2
set last2=%2
set last2=%last2:~-2%
echo ren "%~1.ext" "%last2%_%3_%~4.ext"
```

Remove the Echo if everything looks good

Comment: Ok.. I changed the input to %1, and changed the final line to 
    echo ren "%~2.avi" "%last2%_%3_%~4.avi" and it all works as desired. I didn't know you could group the tokens and pass them as a variable. That's too awesome. Thank you Matt!!